# Recovering IP/Port from Socket Descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, inetd

I'm writing [a clone of inetd](https://github.com/konr/Licio/blob/master/05/myinetd.c) in which I must run a server that prints the IP and port of the client connecting to it.

As I overwrite `STDIN` and `STDOUT` with the socket descriptor, [my initial solution](https://github.com/konr/Licio/blob/master/05/time.c) to do this was to recover the `sockaddr_in` structure, which contains the needed information. Doing this with `getsockname()`, however, is returning an empty structure, with all bits set to 0.

Any idea of what is wrong with my approach? Are there any other approaches I can use to recover the  IP/Port?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As R.. pointed out, you should use [`getpeername`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/getpeername.html). Both that function and [`getsockname`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/getsockname.html) take a file descriptor as its first argument, not a stream pointer (`FILE *`). Use `fileno(stdin)` to get the file descriptor for standard input (or hard-code it to `STDIN_FILENO`, as it's constant).

Also, the last argument to `getsockname` and `getpeername` should be a pointer to `socklen_t`, not a constant, and you should use a `sockaddr_in` for TCP/IP:

```
struct sockaddr_in peeraddr;
socklen_t peeraddrlen = sizeof(peeraddr);
getpeername(STDIN_FILENO, &peeraddr, &peeraddrlen);
```

See a complete example [here](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html).

Comment: OP mentioned "overwriting" stdin and stdout with the file descriptor for the socket, which is improperly worded at best, but it might indicate that the replacement is being done incorrectly and stdin (fd 0) is not actually a socket...

Comment: Dunno if this is *the* problem, but using `struct sockaddr` except as a really ugly substitute for `void *` is always a mistake. You should never have actual objects of type `struct sockaddr`. Always use `struct sockaddr_in`, `struct sockaddr_in6`, or `struct sockadd_storage`, as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use `getpeername`. I suspect your problem is that `getsockname` is returning the information for your own (local) side of the socket, which is probably bound to 0.0.0.0 (meaning it can accept connections from any interface).

**Edit:** I think I found your actual bug reading the code. This line is wrong:

```
getsockname(stdin, &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

The `getsockname` and `getpeername` functions take a `socklen_t *` (a *pointer*) as their third argument, not a `size_t`. The compiler should be telling you about this mistake unless you forgot to include a header with the prototype for `getsockname`. Also, as has already been said, `stdin` is incorrect. Try:

```
socklen_t len = sizeof addr;
getpeername(0, &addr, &len);
```

or (C99 only):

```
getpeername(0, &addr, (socklen_t[1]){sizeof addr});
```

You should also be checking the return value; if you did, you'd see that it's returning errors.

Comment: If you mean that getpeername() returns 0, it means that the function has been successful.

Answer (score 2):

If you need those info for the remote client, you have to call [getpeername()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html).